# Does React automatically remove the CSS applied to a component once it is unmounted?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css and have added some custom animations in tailwind.config.cjs file. I have used this animation in Login component.Once user logs in he will be redirected to the home page it means login component unmounts, once it unmounts do I need to remove the animation applied to the login component manually using useEffect or it will be removed automatically. I have read that you should remove animations manually, but I am not sure. one more question When component unmounts it removes all the CSS applied to it right?

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain this to me in brief.

This is how my tailwind.config.cjs file looks-

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        changeBgDark: {
          "0%, 100%": {  "background-image": "linear-gradient(to left, #4c1d95,#0284c7,blue)",
       
          "background-size":"200%",
          "background-position":"right"
      
        },
          "50%": { "background-image": "linear-gradient(to right,blue,#0284c7,#4c1d95)",
         
          "background-size":"200%",
          "background-position":"left"},
         
        },
        changeBgLight: {
          "0%, 100%": {  "background-image": "linear-gradient(to left, #6d28d9,#0d9488,#06b6d4)",
       
          "background-size":"200%",
          "background-position":"right"
      
        },
          "50%": { "background-image": "linear-gradient(to right,#06b6d4,#0d9488,#6d28d9)",
         
          "background-size":"200%",
          "background-position":"left"},
         
        }
      },
      
      animation: {
        changeBgLight: "changeBgLight 5s ease-in-out infinite",
        changeBgDark: "changeBgDark 5s ease-in-out infinite"

      },
      
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: I don't get it how it's react-specific. React doesn't apply styles to elements, it's the browser which does that

Comment: I have read that It is generally a good idea to clean up any animations or events that are triggered by a component when the component unmounts. This can help prevent memory leaks and improve the overall performance of your application. That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: It was probably about animations created using animation libraries like framer-motion or gsap, not css animation

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't provide this type of function or anything . It would help if you did that manually way.